# DNS error PayPal Buttons API

Tags: html, paypal, dns

PayPal DNS issues, or maybe I'm doing something wrong below to cause this?

> This was working fine until today oddly enough

Here's my PayPal form (uses PayPal buttons API):

```
  <form id="mepr_pp_standard_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="some@email.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Cool Product">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="54">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.000">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://cooliosite.org/return">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://cooliosite.org/cancel?txn_id=54">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="30.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
  </form>
```

I get to PayPal properly after submitting the button form.
[image]

But as soon as I click "Log In" I get this:
[image]

> The live16 part of the PayPal URL changes from time to time, but the DNS error remains the same otherwise.

So can anyone spot that I'm doing something wrong (aside from the insecure HTML form) that would cause this DNS issue - or is PayPal simply having some DNS troubles that are not mentioned in their status page currently?

Comment: Yikes. [Recent relevant thread](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Subscriptions/Error-when-trying-to-make-payment/td-p/1336214). Also see [Downdetector](http://downdetector.com/status/paypal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix has been pushed for this issue. Please proceed for further testing.

Comment: Thank you, I tested this morning and it is in-deed working now.